# Android re-using a cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Is it good practice to re-use a cursor object in android to make multiple queries on a database?  Do I need to call deactivate() between queries?  I am deactivating the cursor after the second query but I am still getting DatabaseObjectNotClosedException warnings in logcat.

Comment: A cursor doesn't make queries, it holds the results of queries. I don't see any reason why you couldn't set it to null and then re-use it.

Comment: After taking another look at the documentation I believe I need to call deactivate() then request a new cursor.  I don't believe setting it to null is necessary before requesting the new cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Both `requery()` and `deactivate()` has been deprecated now (the first one since API 11, the latter since API 16). I'm answering this almost 7 years old question because I believe there's not a correct answer given yet.

**In my experience, re-using a `Cursor` object is a bad practice.** My implementation of `SQLiteOpenHelper` class has several methods, and I close the `Cursor` object in all of those - and I believed that since I closed the `Cursor` object at the end of each method, it was correct. But in some methods I was re-using one `Cursor` object for saving results from multiple queries to it (first I ran a query, then I read and used the result from the `Cursor`, and then I ran a different query which I thought would simply overwrite the old result in an already used `Cursor`). Enabling `StrictMode` proved me wrong. I started getting `DatabaseObjectNotClosedException` crashes.

I fixed it by not re-using the `Cursor` object anymore. Now I create a new `Cursor` variable for each query, then read and save the results, and the I call `close()` method on the `Cursor` and don't use it anymore. If I need to run another query in that method, I deliberately don't use the old `Cursor` anymore, and I always create a new variable. I'm not getting any more warnings or crashes even when `StrictMode` is enabled. I believe that garbage collector does it's job correctly, so I don't think that creating multiple instances of `Cursor` class is a huge issue. Re-using only one `Cursor` object, on the other hand, like an issue seems - hence your warnings and my crashes with `StrictMode`.

I'm not a database expert and I'm still learning best practices in Android programming, but I believe that on this topic I'm correct - don't re-use `Cursor` objects, or you can start getting memory leaks, warnings and possibly even crashes.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you can just set the cursor to something new. I've tried calling deactivate() on it, but that messed up my app, so I decided not to use that. I don't know if it's good practice or not, but it worked fine for me and as far as my testing goes, it doesn't seem to leak or slow down anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `requery()` has been deprecated, bur for some reason `deactivate()` is not. You can't really use one without the other, so I guess you could assume you shouldn't use `deactivate()` . In any case, closing a cursor as soon as you are done with it will get rid of all those pesky `DatabaseObjectNotClosedException`'s. The new loader framework encourages returning new cursors, old ones are automatically closed when you replace them.

Comment: This is not true. You can use deactivate without using requery.  Requery is deprecated because you don't need to call it.  You can just call deactivate then create a new cursor by calling database.rawQuery() or something similar.